# Automatically import secret to google authenticator by uri scheme on Android

Tags: android, google-authenticator

Is there a supported way of launching Google Authenticator on Android?

I found that it's easier to import the secret key by the web link on iOS.

such as:

```
<a href="otpauth://totp/TEST:TEST@gmail.com?algorithm=SHA1&digits=6&issuer=TEST&period=30&secret=ZNSXZIM4GZDP25LCHFC4QVRLVLBNJHU3" target="_blank">click here on iOS</a>
```

Comment: Do you wish to launch the App Google Authenticator via an `Intent` like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234378/intent-to-open-google-authenticator

Comment: No. it's a web, not an app.